# Filter over Kendo grid column with Client Template showing concatenated value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the same scenario as shown in this article
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-menu-customization

What I want is to apply filter to the Name column.
What challenge I am facing is as shown in the article "Name" column is not a plain property coming directly from table, it is concatenation of FirstName and LastName field which are coming from table.
Only setting .Filterable(true) over column does not help.

Can any one please help.

Thanks

Comment: Pre-process your data with [dataSource.schema.parse](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schemaparse) to create a fullName column, and filter that column.

Comment: Thanks @GaloisGirl  for you comment, I am very new to Kendo UI and controls , can you please point me to a simple example of  datasource schema parse to understand how it works or what changes I will have to make to my current grid to get it working ?

Comment: If you look at the link, you have `name: response[i].ProductName` . Do `fullName: response[i].FirstName + '  ' + response[i].LastName` instead.